# android preferencefragment mysteriously called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, listpreference

The first time my android app is launched I bring up a preferencefragment because the user needs to initially make a selection from a list of items and their selection needs to be saved. I extend ListPreference to display the list of items.

The way it should work is the user selects an item from the presented list. This selection
gets saved in SharedPreferences and the app transitions to another fragment. All of this is
working, but for some reason the ListPrefence gets display a second time.

I've put in some logging and discovered that for some reason two ListPreference object are
being constructed...but I know of only one call to create it. I'm somehow missing where/why
the ListPreference constructor is called a second time.

My PreferenceFragment code is simple. It looks like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Log.i("INIT", "ONCREATE");
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.inititems); // load from XML
```

There's only the addPreferencesFromResource() call. No other place in my fragment code
should (as far as I  understand)  cause the ListPreference to be instancitated, but
the logging tells me the ListPreference constructor is called twice and the fragment's
onCreate is called just once.

I'm going to try to do a stack trace from the ListPreference constructor, but I wanted to
see if anyone here has thoughts or suggestions beyond the stack trace. Why would the
constructor be called twice ?

Thanks!
-Mar

Comment: Are you turning the orientation of the screen? When you do that the OnCreate method is called back.

Comment: Hi Trebia. No, no change to the orientation.

Comment: This is probably related to the activity lifecycle, could you describe the exact steps you follow to get twice the call on OnCreate method?

Comment: In onCreate of mainActivity() I call the fragment using this        `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new InitAFragment(), "InitAFragment").commit();` then in the fragment's onCreate I call `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.inititems)`

Comment: I tried to mean, the steps you follow in your device

Comment: Hi and thanks for following up. I used stack tracing to figure out the problem. In onCreate() of main Activity I call PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.references, false). Since R.xml.references instantiated the ListPreference, that's where the second instance of ListPreference comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have referenced the fragment in your layout resource file using android:name="*yourfragment*" as well as at run-time in onCreate(). That would cause it to be loaded twice.